# android-how to launch another app in overlay

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

in iOS, the developer can open another app in an overlay mode. for example when you click on the install button (image 1), the app store opens up in overlay (image 2), so the user can read the info and install without actually leaving the first app. how can we launch an Activity of another app in such mode in android?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can create a floating window using WindowManager by granting Draw Overlays permission only for APIs > 23 (for 23 & below version this permission is always granted)

Comment: but I want to open the Activity of **another app** in floating window. is it possible?

Comment: For that case, that app (targeted app) needs to implement this feature. One thing we can do is we can trigger that action to view targeted activity, now that activity needs to handle this things like to open in app or in floating window mode.